# Dgraph: Can't see API data in Console

Tags: dgraph

I'm running a test Dgraph instance in a dgraph/standalone Docker container, using the github.com/dgraph-io/dgo/v200/protos/api API on port 9080 to write data, but can't see the changes in the Console on port 8000. Using the API to query the previously written data works fine, so I wonder if the API and the Console are somehow using different name spaces?

Answer (score 0):

Are you committing the transaction? I have seen users complaining about this, but they forgot to commit the txn.